# Difference between various evolutionary terms

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, terminology, literature

Could someone kindly explain me the difference between Phylogeny, Phylogenetic Tree, Evolutionary Trees, Phylotype, Clusters, OTU (Open Taxonomic Units). Or if possible please do suggest me a beginner's book on that said topics.

Comment: Any evolutionary biology textbook should cover this, e.g. [Futuyma's *Evolution*](http://www.sinauer.com/evolution-853.html). To me, your question is too open-ended and broad, and it reads as unresearched homework.

Answer (score 1):

**Source of information**

[Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/home.php) is a free online introductory course of evolutionary biology that will probably answer these questions.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) will also make a decent job at answering your questions.

Any introductory book to evolutionary biology would do it.

**To answer your question**

- phylogeny = phylogenetic tree = evolutionary tree: evolutionary relationship between lineages
- phylotype: An observed morphological similarity that is used to classify a group of organisms.
- OTU: An observed genetic similarity that is used to classify a group of organisms.

Both OTU and phylotype are often used for asexual lineages where the concept of species poorly apply. See more info on the concept of species [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species/39669#39669).