# Is it possible for two creature in the same order and have odd haploid chromosome species to reproduce

Tags: genetics, mammals

Take the degu and the rat for example.
The degu has 29 chromosome pairs
Rats have 21 chromosome pairs.
They are only share the same order ( Rodentia )
Would it be possible for them to reproduce?

( also , before someone says " they're not the same species , so obviously not" allow me to remind you of the mule , and the europeans have 1 - 4 percent Neanderthal )

Comment: On the side of the question, [there](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species/39669#39669) are a few words on the concept and definition of species that you might like to read.

Comment: What point are you trying to make about having odd number of chromosome pairs? What difference does it make?