# What is the difference between a human being, a Homo sapiens, and a Neanderthal?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, taxonomy

I know that the Neanderthals were part of the genus *Homo*. How do they relate to other members of the genus, such as *Homo sapiens*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Homo sapiens* / *Homo sapiens sapiens***

Human being, in the popular culture generally refers to modern humans, called either *Homo sapiens* or *Homo sapiens sapiens*. The existence of the two names will make sense when talking about the Neanderthals. In the term *Homo sapiens*, *Homo* indicates the genus and *sapiens* indicates the species. In the term *Homo sapiens sapiens*, the second *sapiens* refers to the subspecies.

***Homo neanderthalis* / *Homo sapiens neanderthalis***

Neanderthals (or Neandertals) is sometimes referred to as a species in the same genus (*Homo*) as *H. sapiens* and sometimes as a subspecies of *H. sapiens*. When considered as a different species then, they are called *Homo neanderthalensis*. When Neanderthals are considered as the same species as *H. sapiens* but different subspecies, then they are called *Homo sapiens neanderthalensis* and modern humans are then called *Homo sapiens sapiens*.

**Related Post**

The post [How-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species) will probably be of interest to you.